# How do I handle n different OpenMP critical sections?

Tags: c, multithreading, queue, openmp

Say I have `n` queues. I also have `n` threads. Each thread may enqueue to any of the `n` queues. How do I make sure that each queue is being accessed by at most 1 thread at any time?

If it was just 1 queue, I'd put the enqueue operation in a `critical` section. However, I can't do that here because putting all enqueue operations in a `critical` section would mean that thread 4 will not be able to write to queue 6 because thread 7 is writing to queue 9. This will lead to bad performance.

I was wondering if I could parallelize all enqueue operations such that each queue itself is written to by at most 1 thread. (Essentially, get a lock on each queue index; but I want to do this idiomatically in OpenMP.)

Comment: 'This will lead to bad performance' - only if there is often contention.  If you are only pushing a pointer onto the queues, how likely is contention with a lock taken for such a short time?

Comment: @MartinJames of course, only when there's contention. And you're right, pushing just a pointer (an int in my case) shouldn't really take much; but it's still possible that a global-ish lock on all queues will slow things down. A index-based lock will be at least as fast as the all-queue-lock, correct?

Comment: Maybe.. if you don't need a lock on the indexing.  Maybe you can do a simple boolean 'inUse' array, and take the hit of an occasional mis-queueing, (sounds lke pool/snooker to me:).

Comment: OpenMP has a lock routines `omp_{init,destroy,set,unset,test}_lock`. if your operation are trivial, an other option is to use atomics

Comment: Pushing single integers onto inter-thread queues does not sound exactly efficient use in any case:(

Answer (score 0):

For the simple case of protecting the access to a static set of objects, OpenMP `critical` sections can be named:

```
#pragma omp critical(somename)
```

Having a thread in critical section `somename` does not prevent another thread from simultaneously entering critical section `othername`. Unnamed critical sections are just a special case, equivalent to naming the section with some opaque system-specific name.

For everything else there are simple and nestable locks. For more information see Section 3.3 *Lock Routines* from the [OpenMP specification](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf).